# URL not updating in address bar after clicking anchor link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a little jQuery for a smooth scroll to anchored links. That much works, but clicking the links does not update the URL in the address bar. I want the URL to update to include the new hash of the clicked link.

I found similar questions on here, but their original code was different enough from mine that I couldn't figure out how to implement it into mine.

```js
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('[name="' + $.attr(this, 'href').substr(1) + '"]').offset().top
    }, 800);

    return false;
});
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
p {
margin-bottom: 200px;
}
</style>
</head>
<a href="#anchor1">Link to Anchor 1</a>
<a href="#anchor2">Link to Anchor 2</a>
<a href="#anchor3">Link to Anchor 3</a>
<a href="#anchor4">Link to Anchor 4</a>
<a name="anchor1"></a>
<p>Anchor 1</p>

<a name="anchor2"></a>
<p>Anchor 2</p>

<a name="anchor3"></a>
<p>Anchor 3</p>

<a name="anchor4"></a>
<p>Anchor 4</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you have `return false` in your click handler, the default behavior of the link is overriden. That's why the location bar doesn't update the URL.

You can manually edit the hash part of the URL:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('[name="' + $.attr(this, 'href').substr(1) + '"]').offset().top
    }, 800);

    // update the URL in location bar
    window.location.hash = $.attr(this, 'href').substr(1);

    return false;
});
```